# How to Display List of Objects in a ListView with a Column for Each Property

Tags: c#, .net, list, visual-studio-2015, windows-forms-designer

After the form calls `InitializeComponent`, I create a `List<DeletionTarget>`:

```
var deletionList = new List<DeletionTarget>();

deletionList.Add(new DeletionTarget("path1", new DateTime(2016, 1, 10), false));
deletionList.Add(new DeletionTarget("path2", new DateTime(2016, 2, 10), true));
deletionList.Add(new DeletionTarget("path3", new DateTime(2016, 3, 10), false));
deletionList.Add(new DeletionTarget("path4", new DateTime(2016, 4, 10), true));
deletionList.Add(new DeletionTarget("path5", new DateTime(2016, 5, 10), false));
```

Where `DeletionTarget` is a simple object which has these properties:

```
public string Path;
public DateTime Period;
public bool Recurse;

public DeletionTarget(string path, DateTime period, bool recurse)
{
    Path = path;
    Period = period;
    Recurse = recurse;
}
```

Next, I call the `InitializeView()` method:

```
public void InitializeListView()
{
    var header1 = listView1.Columns.Add("Path", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    var header2 = listView1.Columns.Add("Period", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    var header3 = listView1.Columns.Add("Recurse", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
}
```

This is supposed to add some columns to the `ListView` (one for each property in the `DeletionTarget` object). Now it is time to add the data to the `ListView`:

```
foreach (var item in deletionList)
{
    var lvi = new ListViewItem(new[] { item.Path, item.Period.ToString(), item.Recurse.ToString() });
    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

When I run the program, this is what my form looks like:

[image]

As you can see, this is pretty useless. I need each item to display on a separate row, with a column for each property. Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening because the `View` option on the `ListView` was set to the wrong option (`LargeIcon`). I was able to overcome this by doing the following:

**In Visual Studio, click the small arrow on the ListView in Designer mode. Select View and then Details:**
[image]

**The items are now displayed on a new row for each instantiation, and all of the Property columns are present:**
[image]